# Array of objects check if it includes key value pair; on which position - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach

I try to check if an array of object has a key value pair with the key `service_tags` and a value of an `array` including the string `"trace"`. If this array has it, I also want to return the position of the object.

My try returns `undefined`.

```
gg.fields =
[  
    { ... },
    {value: "D", display_name: "Nat."},
    {  
       "value":"Likes redwine",
       "display_name":"Trace 2",
       "servicio_tags":[  
          "trace"
       ]
    }
 ]


 //function    

 let traceFieldExists = gg.fields.forEach((field, positionOfTraceField) => {
        if (field.servicio_tags && field.servicio_tags[0] === 'trace') {
            return {
              positionOfTraceField : positionOfTraceField,
              exists : true
            };
          } else {
            return {exists : false};
        }
      });
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: *"Foreach returns void"* JavaScript has no `void` type (it does, bizarrely, have an operator by that name). `Array.prototype.forEach` returns `undefined`.

Comment: Yes I tried to make my title more specific now. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I try to check if an array of object has a key value pair with the key service_tags and a value of an array including the string "trace"

[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) doesn't do that. It **always** returns `undefined`. If you just want to know **if** such an entry exists, use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). If you want to retrieve the first matching entry, use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). If you want the *index* of the first matching entry, use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).

Your edit adds "on which position" to the title, which makes me think you want `findIndex`:

```
let traceFieldIndex = gg.fields.findIndex(field => {
    return field.servicio_tags && field.servicio_tags[0] === 'trace';
});
```

`traceFieldIndex` will contain the index of the first entry in the array for which the callback returned a truthy value, or `-1` if the full array was processed and the callback never returned a truthy value.

If `field.servicio_tags` might have `'trace'` but not at index 0, you might want [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) there:

```
let traceFieldIndex = gg.fields.findIndex(field => {
    return field.servicio_tags && field.servicio_tags.includes('trace');
});
```

That will search all the entries in `field.servicio_tags` instead of just looking at the first one.

Comment: Thanks @T.J. Crowder I used your suggested example. It works great!

Answer (score 0):

According to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) `forEach` return an undefined. SO get the index where the condition is matched you can use reduce function

```js
let ggFields = [{
    'value': "D",
    'display_name': "Nat."
  },
  {
    "value": "Likes redwine",
    "display_name": "Trace 2",
    "servicio_tags": [
      "trace"
    ]
  }
]


let k = ggFields.reduce(function(acc, curr, index) {
  if (curr.hasOwnProperty('servicio_tags') && curr.servicio_tags.includes('trace')) {
    acc.push(index)

  }

  return acc;

}, [])
console.log(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions are great too, but here's one using .map, which will return something for every value in the array, that gets run through the if condition first:

```js
const gg = {};
gg.fields =
[  
  {value: "D", display_name: "Nat."},
  {  
     "value":"Likes redwine",
     "display_name":"Trace 2",
     "servicio_tags":[  
        "trace"
     ]
  }
]


const traceFieldExists = gg.fields.map((field, inx) => {
  if (field.servicio_tags && field.servicio_tags[0] === 'trace'){
    return {
      positionOfTraceField : inx,
      exists : true
    };
  } else {
    return {
      exists: false
    }
  }
});
console.log(traceFieldExists)
```

Cheers!