# how to check key value pair in javascript array of object

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
let devicesInfo = [
  { '96abc32b47fc10c88704b9a799c65b5c05455f4a9ef92013': '::1' },
  { '96abc32b47fc10c88704b9a799c65b5c05455f4a9ef92013': '::1' },
  { '96abc32b47fc10c88704b9a799c65b5c05455f4a9ef92013': '::1' }
  ]

let deviceId= "96abc32b47fc10c88704b9a799c65b5c05455f4a9ef92013"
```

I want check deviceId in deviceinfo array and get its value in result.

Comment: [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) is probably what you ask for. But to be honest, I don't understand what your desired outcome ("check") would be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array of objects check if it includes key value pair; on which position - Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53971269/array-of-objects-check-if-it-includes-key-value-pair-on-which-position-javasc)

Comment: In your  example, you have duplicate objects with the same key and value. If the key repeats will the value always be the same? If not, should it get the value of the first object or last object? Can you also  please share your attempt?

Comment: what do you mean by "check key value pair" ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let devicesInfo = [
  { '96abc32b47fc10c88704b9a799c65b5c05455f4a9ef92013': '::1' },
  { '96abc32b47fc10c88704b9a799c65b5c05455f4a9ef92013': '::1' },
  { '96abc32b47fc10c88704b9a799c65b5c05455f4a9ef92013': '::1' }
];

let deviceId= "96abc32b47fc10c88704b9a799c65b5c05455f4a9ef92013";

let deviceValue = 'Device not found';

devicesInfo.forEach(device => {
  deviceValue = device[deviceId] ?? deviceValue;
});

console.log(deviceValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let devicesInfo = [
  { '96abc32b47fc10c88704b9a799c65b5c05455f4a9ef92013': '::1' },
  { '96abc32b47fc10c88704b9a799c65b5c05455f4a9ef92013': '::1' },
  { '96abc32b47fc10c88704b9a799c65b5c05455f4a9ef92013': '::1' }
  ]

let deviceId= "96abc32b47fc10c88704b9a799c65b5c05455f4a9ef92013"

const getDevice = (id) => {
  devicesInfo.filter((val) => val.hasOwnProperty(id));
  return devicesInfo[0] ? devicesInfo[0][id] : undefined;
};

console.log(getDevice(deviceId)); // '::1'

console.log(getDevice('fhqwhgads')); // undefined
```